# workbook won't open when opening is called from a workbook that has been itself opened by a third workbook

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I face an issue on vba, to explain myself, from one file (let's call it file1), by clicking on a button, I open another workbook(file2), and when reaching this workbook, it asks to open another one(file3), but it doesn't.... (when I write" set WBK=workbook(file3), it gives me the error "subscript out of range")

Indeed, when I open directly file2, it opens file 3 without any issue

does someone have an answer about it?

IN FILE 1

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

        UserForm1.Hide

        Workbooks.Open ("Boss4 copy.xlsm")

End Sub
```

IN FILE 2(Boss4 copy)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyScript As String
Dim MyFiles As String
Dim MySplit As Variant
Dim N As Long
Dim Fname As String
Dim mybook As Workbook


On Error Resume Next
MyPath = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")

MyScript = _
"set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
           "set theFiles to (choose file of type " & _
         " {""com.microsoft.Excel.xls"",""org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet""} " & _
           "with prompt ""Please select a file or files"" default location alias """ & _
           MyPath & """ multiple selections allowed true) as string" & vbNewLine & _
           "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
           "return theFiles"

MyFiles = MacScript(MyScript)
On Error GoTo 0

    MySplit = Split(MyFiles, ",")
    For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

        ' Get the file name only and test to see if it is open.
        Fname = Right(MySplit(N), Len(MySplit(N)) - InStrRev(MySplit(N), Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
        If bIsBookOpen(Fname) = False Then

            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MySplit(N))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            MsgBox "the file: " & MySplit(N) & " is already opened."
        End If

    Next N
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    **Here's the error "subscript out of range"**
    Set WBK = Workbooks(Fname)

    Else: Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

STILL IN FILE 2

```
Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide (via code or images if there is no code) a concise, repeatable example that others can run in order to repeat the error. Without that it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! 
I was thinking that would be indeed difficult for anybody to help me, thus I updated my post, please let me now if you need further informations!

Comment: Psssst.. that's a *comment*, not an *answer* ;-) I think you need to read [mcve] and apply whatever you learn from it to this post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm absolutely new on this website, thanks for editing my question, I didn't find how to include in my code the parts you included!

Comment: I forgot an important thing, I'm currently running excel on Macintosh, thus my code maybe won't run on windows os...

Comment: What's the value `MySplit(N)` when you try to open? are you sure you're passing path correctly? especially for mac sytanx

Comment: Won't `MsgBox MySplit` throw an error?  (It would on a Windows version)

Comment: Hi guys, I'm sorry, I just tested again the code I posted, and I realised it was not correctly edited.
thus I Just edited my post, and this code should give you the same error  I get.
Thanks a lot again for your answers!!

Comment: @SCRWH Since you seem pretty receptive to suggestions, to make your question better you should format your code by ensuring 4 spaces are in front of it all of it. (select it use ctrl+k shortcut).

Comment: @CodyG. Ok I understand better how to indent my code now :)
I updated my post with your advices!

Comment: My suggestion is to do a `debug.print "Fname: "+Fname` right before `Set WBK = Workbooks(Fname)` see what you get for the third file, or use a debug point on that line and use the locals window to inspect `Fname`.

Comment: @CodyG. the error is still there, and when I look at the locals window, WBK is given "empty"...

Comment: Yeah but what Fname are you supplying it?

Comment: @CodyG. Fname gives me "test" (the file I opened with the code)

Comment: So when you step through it "test" is the Fname that gives you the error? (Basically what I'm asking is if you were to run the next line through the step debugger (i.e. hitting F8, sorry I don't know what it is on Mac), that filename gives you an error.)

Comment: It may help to see an example of what `MySplit(N)` could look like.  What's `mySplit(0)` and `mySplit(1)` going to be?

Comment: Is file `test` definitely an Excel file? ,And is it open when your code crashes?  If it's not open, then the main error isn't in the `Set WBK = Workbooks(Fname)` - that's just the line that is finally crashing - the error would be in the `Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MySplit(N))` line which won't report its error due to the `On Error Resume Next` statement immediately before it.

Comment: I tested my code by replacing the procedure after Workbook_Open by "getopenfilename", and as  @YowE3K said, the issue is more likely to be caused by the 3rd file that doesn't open, and thus, setting a variable to something that doesn't exist gives me the subscript out of range error. I also found out that when closing the 1st file before opening the second one would resolve the issue. But I'm pretty sure it's impossible since the opening of the 3rd file is asked at the opening of the 2nd file.... Am I right?
If I'm wrong,is it a way to do it?
Anyway, thanks you guys a lot for your help!!!

Comment: JSYK, you can't open two workbooks with the same name. I don't know if you're running into that issue or not. As BruceWayne suggested, it would be helpful to see what MySplit(N) is.  I'm not quite sure why closing the 1st before opening the second would fix it unless it's the same name.